# App shutting down

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

So I want to implement a ProgressBar and set it on 100% but somehow it keeps crashing in the Emulator.

Heres the Code(MainActivity.java):

```
package com.example.schwarzerritter.remotec;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar fuelBar;




    public Button lDoor;

    public void lDoorPageOpen() {
        lDoor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lDoor);//weist unseren Button lDoor in Java zu
        lDoor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent lDoorPage = new Intent(MainScreen.this, lDoorPageOpen.class);//deklarieren eines intents
                startActivity(lDoorPage);//starte intent lDoorPage
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        fuelBar.setProgress(100);
        lDoorPageOpen();
        fuelBar =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.fuelB);

    }
}
```

and this is the .xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.schwarzerritter.remotec.MainScreen"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RemoteC"
        android:id="@+id/remoteC"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lDoor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="LOCK"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/remoteC"
        android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/acB"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fuelB"
        android:layout_width="94dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="FUEL"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/locB"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/locB"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/remoteC"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="41dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/acB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="AC"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lDoor"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/locB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="LOCATION"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fuelB"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/acB"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.859" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/engB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="ENGINE START"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locB"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/fuelB"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="310dp" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: where is your stacktrace?

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
  fuelBar =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.fuelB);
        fuelBar.setProgress(100);
        lDoorPageOpen();
        

    }

Comment: That's no stacktrace, that's a method. May the 4th be with  you.

Comment: you have mapped your progressbar after calling method which is wrong...you have to map your progressbar first and then you can set progress to it...Implement above code and it will fix your error.

Comment: you didn't initialize fuelBar, you probably have NullPointerException. please look at your stacktrace before you post a question.

Answer (score 0):

First Initialize Progressbar then use setProgress(100).

```
fuelBar =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.fuelB);
lDoorPageOpen();
fuelBar.setProgress(100);
```

Comment: The button and progressBar have the same ID, also, so  while this is correct, the app will still crash

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of your code, Progress bar must initialized before set progress.